# How to tell android maven plugin to use different shell under Windows 7?

Tags: android, powershell, cmd, maven-3, android-maven-plugin

I am trying to overcome the length limit of `cmd.exe` when building an Android project on Windows7.

I've already mapped `M2_REPO` and Android SDK to subst drives, but I still hit the limit due to large number of packages in the project I am building.

I tried running my mvn build from Powershell and Git Bash (which is a MINGW32), however in both cases I get the same error showing that Maven runs `cmd.exe` as one of the steps.

Is there a way to tell `android-maven-plugin` to use other shell than `cmd.exe` so it calls Git Bash instead (or Powershell)?

---

The error I am getting looks like this:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.6.1:dex (default-dex) on project MyProject: MojoExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = cmd.exe /X /C ""c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\bin\java" -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -jar A:\build-tools\19.1.0\lib\dx.jar --dex --output=... (logs of jars from repository), Result = 1 -> [Help 1]`

The command seems to be 7753 characters long as printed in the output, which is less than 8192 supposed limit of `cmd.exe`, but in the past I was able to fix it just by adding subst drives so I assume that this is still the case of hitting the command line length limit. And I cannot make it any shorter since all jars I have there are references to the apklib files from maven repository mapped to `M:`.

(Maven 3.0.5)

Comment: We would take a pull request that makes the executable configurable ... although not sure what it could be alternatively to cmd.